# Refreshing DBExpress data

Tags: c++, c++builder, dbexpress

I have a simple DBExpress application using a SQLite database on C++ builder XE3.

The UI is having a few DBGrids and DBNavigators. The DBGrids are connected to TDataSources that are connected to TClientDataSets. The TClientDataSets gets data from TDataProviders, that are getting data from a TSQLDataSet. Everyting connected to a TSQLConnection.

The application works fine except when data is posted by another db component, not related to the application. To get the new 'remote' data, I have to click the Refresh button on the navigator twice(2).

I'm getting the same behavior with the following code:

```
        mClientDBSession.insertImageFile(getFileNameNoPath(f), "Note..");
        DBNavigator1->BtnClick(nbRefresh);
        DBNavigator1->BtnClick(nbRefresh);
```

The mClientDBSession is a database object not related to DBExpress. The insertImageFile inserts a db record directly into the SQLite database and is synchronous, so i know the DB got the data after the function exits.

Oddly, if I don't call the BtnClick(nbRefresh) twice, the data is not updated , afaik from looking at the DBGrid.

Ideally I would have a timer automatically updating the DBExpress components with new server data every so often.